# How to Delete a list of items inside a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I'm working on a asp.net MVC application, I have a list of selected Items from a Products Table that contains(ProductName, Price);

I have 2 buttons, one that clears one item(working)

DeleteOneItem Partial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteItemCheckbox", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { 
 UpdateTargetId = "div_print", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
    <input type="number" name="ProductId" hidden value="@item.ProductId" />
    <div>Product Name :   @item.ProductName    </div>
    <p>Product Price :  @item.ProductPrice $  </p>
    <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-info" value="Delete Item" /><br />
}
```

DeleteOneItem  Method:

```
 public ActionResult DeleteItem(int ProductId)
    {

        List<Product> AddedToCart = new List<Product>();
        AddedToCart = (List<Product>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"];

        var deleteSelecedItem = AddedToCart.Where(a => a.ProductID.Equals(pId)).FirstOrDefault();

        AddedToCart.Remove(deleteSelecedItem);

        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            itemsNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Session["items"]),
            SumVM = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sum"]),
            AddToCartList = AddedToCart
        };

        return View("Cart", viewModel);
    }
```

And the other one that delete the selected items but i can't figure it out how to do it .

I started by putting all the selected items inside a list first by adding
a check input beside each element.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@item.ProductId" 
id="defaultCheck1" name="employeeIdsToDelete">
 ....
 ....
 ....
 <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-info" value="Delete Selected  Items" /><br />
```

And In the controller i was able to get the list of all selected items IDs

```
public ActionResult DeleteItemCheckbox(List<int> employeeIdsToDelete)
    {
     var ListP=employeeIdsToDelete.ToList();
     ..
```

now I already have a list called ItemsSelectedToBuy that contains the selected product that users wants to buy.
it in the Session["listOfSelectedItems"];

What I want to do is to delete all items selected in the employeeIdsToDelete 
from the Session["listOfSelectedItems"] which is a list of product selected.

Comment: `var deleteSelecedItem = AddedToCart.Where(a => a.ProductID != pId).FirstOrDefault();` use not equal to avoide removal from list. It will give you the list of items without the items you want to remove.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks for the help

Comment: but the first button for deleting one item is already working, what I want to do is to delete multiple items

Comment: Okay, then use for loop to remove a list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this.

```
 public ActionResult DeleteItemCheckbox(List<int> employeeIdsToDelete)
    {

        List<Product> AddedToCart = new List<Product>();
        AddedToCart = (List<Product>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"];

        var deleteSelecedItem = AddedToCart.Where(a => 
         a.ProductID.Equals(employeeIdsToDelete)).FirstOrDefault();

        List<Product> finallist = AddedToCart
                              .Where(x => !employeeIdsToDelete.Contains(x.ProductID))
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult DeleteItemCheckbox(List<int> employeeIdsToDelete)
{
    var ListP = employeeIdsToDelete.ToList();

    foreach (var item in ListP)
    {
        (List<Product>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"].RemoveAll(x => x.ID == item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,but it's giving me error on "item" cannot convert int to Product-->table

Comment: I didn’t know what the session type was so I made a guess

Comment: it's a list of product table                                                                   
            List<Product> myList = new List<Product>();
           Session["listOfSelectedItems"] =myList;

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> AddedToCart = new List<Product>();
AddedToCart = (List<Product>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"];

foreach (int item in employeeIdsToDelete)
{
     employeeIdsToDelete.RemoveAll(X => X.ProductID == item);
}
```

Comment: While this answer might be a valid solution for the question, it is recommended that also explain exactly what you are doing and how it fixes the OP's problem. This helps new developers understand what is going on and learn how to fix the same issue in the future. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult DeleteItemCheckbox(List<int> employeeIdsToDelete)
    {
            var ListP = employeeIdsToDelete.ToList();
            List<int> listOfSelectedItems = (List<int>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"];
            List<int> finallist = listOfSelectedItems
                                  .Where(x => !employeeIdsToDelete.Contains(x))
                                  .ToList();
            Session["listOfSelectedItems"] = finallist;
    }
```

Comment: i did this in order to remove all errors                                                                             
   var ListP = employeeIdsToDelete.ToList();
            List<Product> listOfSelectedItems = 
   (List<Product>)Session["listOfSelectedItems"];
            List<Product> finallist = listOfSelectedItems
                                  .Where(x => !employeeIdsToDelete.Contains(x))
                                  .ToList();
              Session["listOfSelectedItems"] = finallist;

Comment: but when i put a breakpoint on the method it's showing me the the  employeeIdsToDelete is null, I guess i should try to fix my view because o submit I'm returning @item.ProductId which is an int and the method is taking a list of product now

Comment: You need to post the ids to delete from the view.How are you populating employeeIdsToDelete ? You can create collection using jquery and hidden field.There are multiple ways to pass data from view to controller